Dynamically changing underlying crate code depending on cargo features
I have a rust workspace which looks like the following:
* program_a
  * libloragw - features = [ manufacturer_a ]
  * dependency_a
    * libloragw
* program_b
  * libloragw - features = [ manufacturer_b ]
  * dependency_a
    * libloragw
* dependency_a
  * libloragw
* libloragw


At the moment it consists of 2 binary packages, and the rest are libraries.
The 2 binary packages are tools which do similiar things, they interface with some hardware through the libloragw package.
The libloragw package is a crate i've created which statically compiles, and generates bindings for a third party library provided by different hardware manufacturers.
I have added 2 feature flags to the libloragw package

manufacturer_a
manufacturer_b

program_a includes libloragw = { path = "../libloragw", features = ["manufacturer_a"] }
program_b includes libloragw = { path = "../libloragw", features = ["manufacturer_b"] }
the intent behind these flags is to clone the relevant driver code from the relevant manufacturer and compile it into a static library so the application can function, whilst keeping everything else the same.
When compiling programs individually, everything works as expected. However when compiling the whole workspace, cargo only compiles the libloragw package a single time, combining the flags [manufacturer_a, manufacturer_b]. Obviously this doesn't work (for me) because only 1 instance of the static library can be included at any given time.
Which brings me to the root of my question: How can i include a static library (which can change) depending on which binary package is being built in my workspace?

I don't think you can with a single workspace, features are unified across the workspace.
